# What is Pro Webmasters to Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

I came to pro webmasters from stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is mainly use for asking programming questions. It could be web programming questions. So, how about Pro Webmasters? I can basically asking same question on either 2 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro Webmasters is just one of many [StackExchange Q&A sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).  Each site in the network focuses on one subject area:

- StackOverlow: programming
- Pro Webmasters: running websites

There is little overlap between these two sites.  Questions about search engine optimization and internet marketing are off topic at StackOverflow.   Questions about debugging JavaScript are off topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I ask software / service recommendation for running websites here?

Comment: Recommendations aren't welcome on almost all the stackexchange sites. "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers." - from http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: Please let me add that cross-posting is [not generally accepted on StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).